# Zipfile file in cloud(amazon s3) without writing it first to local file(no write privileges)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, zip

I need to zip some files in amazon s3 without needing to write them to file locally first. Ideally my code worked in development but i don't have many write privileges in production.

```
folder = output_dir
files = fs.glob(folder)
f = BytesIO()
zip = zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'a', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
for file in files:
    filename = os.path.basename(file)
    image = fs.get(file, filename)

    zip.write(filename)
zip.close()
```

the proplem is at this line in production

```
image = fs.get(file, filename)
```

Because i don't have write privileges.
My last resort is to write to /tmp/ directory which i have privileges to.
Is there a way to zip files from a url path or directly in the cloud?

Comment: Used temp file and named temporary files.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using python tempfile which ended up being a perfect solution.

Using [NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) gave me the guarantee to create named and system visible temporary files that could be deleted automatically. No manual work.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.